# Can we have a projection matrix which can connect between two orthogonal state?

Tags: operators, linear-algebra

Suppose we have a vector space spanned by 7 states, say {$\left| a \right>$, $\left|b \right>$,... $\left|g\right>$}

And there exist a projector operator *P* which operates into this space.

Now, if $\left | a\right>$ is orthogonal to $\left |b \right>$, then can we infer that-
$\left< a \right|$ *P* $\left| b \right>$=0 ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

For a projection (idempotent) operator where $$P^2=P$$ and $$P\left|\psi\right>=p\left|\psi\right>$$ it is straightforward to show$^1$  that $P$ has eigenvalues $p= \{0,1\}$

So for any two distinct states $\left| m \right>$, $\left| n \right>$ that are eigenstates of $P$ then $$\left<m|P|n \right> =+1\left<m|n \right>=\left<m|n \right>\ \text{or}\\ \left<m|P|n \right> =\left<m|(0\times|n \right>)=0$$ where $\left| m \right>,\left| n \right>\in \{\left| a \right>\ldots \left| g \right> \}$

But given the states $\{\left| a \right>\ldots \left| g \right>\}$ are orthogonal, then $$\left<m|n \right>=0$$  where $\left| m \right>,\left| n \right>\in \{\left| a \right>\ldots \left| g \right> \}$

So it is true that, $$\left<m|P|n \right> =0$$ for a projector operating in space of orthogonal states regardless of what the eigenvalue for $P$ is.

$^1$ If $P^2 = P(P)$, then $P(P(\psi)) = P(p \psi) = p^2 \psi$, and this also equals $p\psi$ and therefore $p^2 =p$ or $p=\{0,1\}$.

Comment: This is only true if $P$ onto exactly one of the basis states. It is no longer true if $P$ projects onto a subspace of dimension $\ge 2$ or if $P$ projects onto a state that is not in the basis

Comment: How does this contradict my answer? Are you saying that since there are two distinct eigenvalues then there can only be two distinct eigenvectors? Or that the number of eigenvalues equals the dimension of the space? What does "_true if P onto exactly one_" mean?

Comment: The issue is that the states $|a\rangle,|b\rangle$... may not be eigenstates at all. For example if $P = \left(\begin{array}{cc} 1&0\\0&0\end{array}\right)$, $|a\rangle = \left(\begin{array}{c}1\\1\end{array}\right)$ and $|b\rangle = \left(\begin{array}{c}1\\-1\end{array}\right)$ then $\langle b | P| a \rangle = 1$ even though $|a\rangle \ne |b\rangle$ and $\langle b|a\rangle = 0$.

Comment: The OP assumes that they _are_ eigenstates of $P$. He states that $P$ is an operator on the state space and that the $|a>,|b>,...$ are eigenstates. Why would you think otherwise, and again what does "_true if P onto exactly one_" mean?